# merge 2 dataframes in Pandas: join on some columns, sum up others

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two dataframes on specific columns (key1, key2) and sum up the values for another column (value).

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key1': range(4), 'key2': range(4), 'value': range(4)})
   key1  key2  value
0     0     0      0
1     1     1      1
2     2     2      2
3     3     3      3

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key1': range(2, 6), 'key2': range(2, 6), 'noise': range(2, 6), 'value': range(10, 14)})
   key1  key2  noise  value
0     2     2      2     10
1     3     3      3     11
2     4     4      4     12
3     5     5      5     13
```

I want this result:

```
   key1  key2  value
0     0     0      0
1     1     1      1
2     2     2     12
3     3     3     14
4     4     4     12
5     5     5     13
```

In SQL terms, I want:

```
SELECT df1.key1, df1.key2, df1.value + df2.value AS value
FROM df1 OUTER JOIN df2 ON key1, key2
```

I tried two approaches:

approach 1

```
concatenated = pd.concat([df1, df2])
grouped = concatenated.groupby(['key1', 'key2'], as_index=False)
summed = grouped.agg(np.sum)
result = summed[['key1', 'key2', 'value']]
```

approach 2

```
joined = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['key1', 'key2'], suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
joined = joined.fillna(0.0)
joined['value'] = joined['value_1'] + joined['value_2']
result = joined[['key1', 'key2', 'value']]
```

Both approaches give the result I want, but I wonder if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know about simpler, but you can get a little more concise:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(["key1", "key2"], as_index=False)["value"].sum()
   key1  key2  value
0     0     0      0
1     1     1      1
2     2     2     12
3     3     3     14
4     4     4     12
5     5     5     13
```

Depending on your tolerance for chaining ops, you might want to break this onto multiple lines anyway, though (four tends to be close to my upper limit, in this case concat-groupby-select-sum).

Comment: It does *seem* like their ought to be a more concise way... like a merge-time aggregation.

Comment: I was looking for a magical function that does everything in an optimised way.

Comment: I chose the approach 2, and chained ops as much as possible because it is faster this way.

Comment: @Laurie: chaining operations (as opposed to the same operations broken up onto different lines, I mean) doesn't affect the speed.