# Combine two pandas dataframes adding corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have two dataframes like these:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,0,3], 'B':[0,0,1], 'C':[0,2,2]}, index =['a','b','c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0], 'B':[2,1]}, index =['a','c'])
```

df1 and df2:

```
   | A | B | C |          | A | B |    
---|---|---|---|       ---|---|---|
 a | 1 | 0 | 0 |        a | 0 | 2 |   
 b | 0 | 0 | 2 |        c | 0 | 1 |
 c | 3 | 1 | 2 |
```

And the expected result is:

```
   | A | B | C |
---|---|---|---|
 a | 1 | 2 | 0 |
 b | 0 | 0 | 2 |
 c | 3 | 2 | 2 |
```

I'm having problems with this because there may be missing columns/rows in any of the dataframes (df1 may not have all columns and rows df2 has)

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583668/merge-2-dataframes-in-pandas-join-on-some-columns-sum-up-others

Comment: I already checked that, but my problem is that there is not a predefined set of columns both dataframes share. So, I can't use them as keys to concatenate the dataframes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going by the idea in the answer for this question - [merge 2 dataframes in Pandas: join on some columns, sum up others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583668/merge-2-dataframes-in-pandas-join-on-some-columns-sum-up-others)

Since in your case, the indexes are the ones that are common, you can use [`pandas.concat()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for the two DataFrames, then [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) based on the index, and then take sum on it. Example -

```
In [27]: df1
Out[27]:
   A  B  C
a  1  0  0
b  0  0  2
c  3  1  2

In [28]: df2
Out[28]:
   A  B
a  0  2
c  0  1

In [29]: pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(level=0).sum()
Out[29]:
   A  B  C
a  1  2  0
b  0  0  2
c  3  2  2
```

Comment: Thanks. I would only add ``.fillna(0)`` at the end of the In[29] command to remove ``nan``s