# sum two pandas dataframe columns, keep non-common rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[I just asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771675/pandas-concat-merge-and-sum-one-column#33771793) but then
 realized, it wasn't the *right* question.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to combine two data frames that actually have the same columns, but may or may not have common rows (indices of a MultiIndex). I'd like to combine them taking the sum of one of the columns, but leaving the other columns.

According to the accepted answer, the approach may be something like:

```
def mklbl(prefix,n):
    try:
        return ["%s%s" % (prefix,i)  for i in range(n)]
    except:
        return ["%s%s" % (prefix,i) for i in n]



mi1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A',4), mklbl('C',2)])

mi2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A',[2,3,4]), mklbl('C',2)])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(len(mi1)), 'b':np.arange(len(mi1)),'c':np.arange(len(mi1)), 'd':np.arange(len(    mi1))[::-1]}, index=mi1).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)    

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(len(mi2)), 'b':np.arange(len(mi2)),'c':np.arange(len(mi2)), 'd':np.arange(len(    mi2))[::-1]}, index=mi2).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)


df1 = df1.add(df2.pop('b'))
```

but the problem is this will fail as the indices don't align.

This is close to what I'm trying to achieve, except that I lose rows that are not common to the two dataframes:

```
df1['b'] = df1['b'].add(df2['b'], fill_value=0)
```

But this gives me:

```
Out[197]: 
       a   b  c  d
A2 C0  0   4  0  5
   C1  1   6  1  4
A3 C0  2   8  2  3
   C1  3  10  3  2
A4 C0  4   4  4  1
   C1  5   5  5  0
```

When I want:

```
In [197]: df1
Out[197]: 
       a   b  c  d
A0 C0  0  0  0  7
   C1  1  2  1  6
A1 C0  2  4  2  5
   C1  3  6  3  4
A2 C0  0   4  0  5
   C1  1   6  1  4
A3 C0  2   8  2  3
   C1  3  10  3  2
A4 C0  4   4  4  1
   C1  5   5  5  0
```

Note: in response to @RandyC's comment about the XY problem... the *specific* problem is that I have a class which reads data and returns a dataframe of 1e9 rows. The columns of the data frame are `latll, latur, lonll, lonur, concentration, elevation`. The data frame is indexed by a `MultiIndex` (lat, lon, time) where time is a datetime. The rows of the two dataframes may/may not be the same (IF they exist for a given date, the lat/lon will be the same... they are grid cell centers). `latll, latur, lonll, lonur` are calculated from lat/lon. I want to sum the `concentration` column as I add two data frames, but not change the others.

Comment: This smells a bit like an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you give a little more detail on the overarching problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Also, if you use random data, please use and provide a seed. That way we'll have the same result/expected as you.

Comment: @RandyC yes, I suppose my original question was, but the answer there was direct and useful, so rather than carrying on ... I thought it made sense to pose a new question with my *actual* problem.

Comment: @AndyHayden sorry! I had forgotten to add the mklbl function in this post. Corrected.

Comment: I believe I found a solution: `result = df1.combine_first(df2)` followed by, `result['b']= result['b'].add(df2['b'], fill_value=0)` but perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: I meant to also comment, when I do that add I get a `ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names`. It's strange as I thought add was an outer rather than inner-join.

Comment: @John you should add that as a self-answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answering, there was an error in the comment above that caused a double adding. This is correct:

```
newdata = df2.pop('b')
result = df1.combine_first(df2)
result['b']= result['b'].add(newdata, fill_value=0)
```

seems to provide the solution to my use-case.